# Django setting.py error

Tags: python, mysql, django, orm

I have the following code with the following settings. But I always get an error in my settings ... 
MySQL version is 5 and Django the last version.
Python 3.7

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
import sys
sys.path.append("/home/test")


if __name__ == "__main__":
     os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "standAlone.myScript")
     from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
     execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
```

This is my myScript:

```
# settings.py
from django.conf import settings


#settings.configure(
    DATABASE_ENGINE    = " ",
    DATABASE_NAME      = " ",
    DATABASE_USER      = " ",
    DATABASE_PASSWORD  = " ",
    DATABASE_HOST      = " ",
    DATABASE_PORT      = " ",
   # INSTALLED_APPS     = ("myApp")
)

from django.db import models
from myApp.models import *
```

And this is my settings.py:

```
DATABASE_ENGINE    = 'django.db.backends.mysql'
DATABASE_NAME      = 'DATABASE_NAME'
DATABASE_USER      = '****'
DATABASE_PASSWORD  = '****'
DATABASE_HOST      = '127.0.0.1'
DATABASE_PORT      = '3306'
```

I have the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/test/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 443, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/test/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 382, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/home/test/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 252, in fetch_command
    app_name = get_commands()[subcommand]
  File "/home/test/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 101, in get_commands
    apps = settings.INSTALLED_APPS
  File "/home/test/django/utils/functional.py", line 184, in inner
    self._setup()
  File "/home/test/django/conf/__init__.py", line 42, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
  File "/home/test/django/conf/__init__.py", line 93, in __init__
    mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
  File "/home/test/django/utils/importlib.py", line 35, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/home/test/standAlone/myScript.py", line 6
    DATABASE_ENGINE    = "django.db.backends.mysql",
    ^
```

Comment: Which version of django are you using? You say latest, do you mean latest official version (1.4) or are you using experiemental 1.5 code from the git repository?

Comment: Aslo, I assume you mean Python 2.7 since 3.7 doesn't exist? You might want to correct that.

Comment: You've cleverly failed to quote the actual exception. I assume it's `IndentationError`.

Comment: If you're using the latest version of Django, you *clearly* need to read the documentation. That's not even how you specify databases anymore. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/settings/#databases

Answer (score 2):

In line 5 in myScript.py you have a `#` which comments a line out. Then, I think that the line  6 `DATABASE_ENGINE    = " ",` will be a syntax error (though the traceback does not seem to include this).

There are other problems too. The way you import things will cause the settings.py database settings to be overwritten with empty values in line 5 onwards in myScript.py. Unless this is what you want, a correct way to do this (in myScript.py) is:

```
# settings.py
from django.conf import settings

from django.db import models
from myApp.models import *
```

That is, specify the settings in settings.py, don't overwrite them in myScript.py.

If you do need to override the settings for whatever reason, then just remove the `#` at line 5, and things might work.

Next time, please try to solve syntax errors by yourself, it will be much faster than posting to stack overflow.